# How to fix MATLAB warnings & error when starting?

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have installed MATLAB R2015a. when I start it few warnings are displayed in command window:

```
Warning: Function circshift has the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential name conflict.
Warning: Function circshift has the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential name conflict.
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 86)
  In startup (line 6)
  In matlabrc (line 225) 
Warning: Function circshift has the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential name conflict.
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 86)
  In startup (line 7)
  In matlabrc (line 225) 
Warning: Function circshift has the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential name conflict.
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 86)
  In startup (line 8)
  In matlabrc (line 225) 
Warning: Function circshift has the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential name conflict.
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 86)
  In startup (line 9)
  In matlabrc (line 225) 
Warning: Function circshift has the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to avoid a potential name conflict.
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 86)
  In startup (line 10)
  In matlabrc (line 225)
```

and when I type `X = zeros(` an error is displayed in command window:

```
Exception in thread "QueuedMatlabWorker" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.ProductFilterModel$InstalledState
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterProductPrefs.getSelectedProductsFromPref(DocCenterProductPrefs.java:47)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterProductPrefs.getProductFilterModel(DocCenterProductPrefs.java:33)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterDocConfigParams.<init>(DocCenterDocConfigParams.java:37)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterDocConfig.getLocalConfig(DocCenterDocConfig.java:77)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterDocConfig.getInstance(DocCenterDocConfig.java:65)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterReferenceRetrievalStrategy.getInstance(DocCenterReferenceRetrievalStrategy.java:43)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.DocCenterReferenceRetrievalStrategy.createDataRetriever(DocCenterReferenceRetrievalStrategy.java:79)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.functioncall.MFunctionCall.getReferenceData(MFunctionCall.java:520)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.functioncall.MFunctionCall.getSignatureString(MFunctionCall.java:489)
    at com.mathworks.mlwidgets.help.functioncall.MFunctionCall.createSignatureString(MFunctionCall.java:233)
    at com.mathworks.mde.functionhints.QueuedMatlabWorker$2.run(QueuedMatlabWorker.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix these?

---

more precisely, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> this error is repeated. I think its somewhere in MATLAB which shows function inputs.

Comment: Regarding the first, you may have a self-defined function named `circshift` in your path and hence the warning message. How to fix this? Do what the warning message suggests. i.e. rename it

Comment: @Adriaan the reason I asked is that, I even did not press `Enter` to execute my command

Comment: @MJay That happens with MATLAB from time to time.  It uses a Java backend and if it runs for a while, you get these random Java errors.  I found that simply closing and restarting solved the problem.  As for your `circshift` warning, do what MATLAB says and rename the file.

Comment: If you don't know where that `circshift` function exists, enter `which circshift` , this will tell you where

Comment: What is in `startup.m` ? MATLAB executes `startup.m` every time you open it. The error trace shows that the error is there somewhere

Comment: The first error comes from startup. The second error is internal MATLAB crash, the java process that gives help to autocomplete (`functionhints`) function is crashing. It is likely that something in your `startup.m` is causing this behaviour also.

Comment: @MJay: Try toggling the [function hint setting](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/170474-how-to-turn-on-the-function-hint) in the preferences on and off and see if that helps the second error.

Comment: [Possibly related error](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232238-java-error-when-using-fx-button).

Comment: @gnovice I didtoggling and also restarting, they did not help.

Comment: @MJay of the solutions proposed in the post linked by gnovice, the 3rd one (C) is saying that this can be caused by shadowing functions with custom ones, which is exactly what your first error here is. Stop ignoring useful advice and do something about that `startup.m`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have deleted `startup.m` but those errorss are not related to that file and are still remained.

Comment: Have you installed a matlab toolbox? If that's the case, then the problem is caused by that. The matlabrc.m file may still be causing problems. Ultimately, if it is nota because any of that (I think it is), you need to reinstall matlab

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have reinstalled MATLAB many times! The interesting point is that, when I install 64-bit version, there's no problem! I have not installed any toolbox yet.

Comment: @MJay if that is teh case, contacct mathworks